# Need answer to the following question show each factor is a retract of $\Pi f_i$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Source: The first course in Topology Conover
Pg 97,#7

I am not a student and have tried to solve it but am stumped.

**Show that each factor is a retract of $\Pi$ $f_i$**

I know what a retract is but this problem
is perplexing me, cause of its generality.

Can I use these theorems?

$(1)$ Let $n>1$ and let $X_1,…,X_n$ be topological spaces and
let $Y$ be a topological space and $f:Y \mapsto \Pi X_i$
Then $f$ is continuous for $1\leq i  \leq n$ if $ \pi_i\circ f$
is continuous

I thought it might apply because of the next one

$(2)$ Let $n>1$ and let $X_1,…,X_n$ be topological spaces and
let Y be a topological space and for each $i \quad1\leq i \leq n$
. let $f_i:Y \mapsto X_i$ Then the function  $f:Y \mapsto \Pi X_i$ defined by $f(x)=(f_1(x),…,f_n(x)$) is continuous if each
$f_i$ are too

**Work so far**

So to show $f_i$:Y$\mapsto X_i$ is a retract of $\Pi  f_i$:Y$\mapsto$ $\Pi X_i$

I have to find a continuous map $r_i:\Pi X_i \mapsto X_i$
such that $r_i\circ \Pi f_i$=$f_i$

From $(2)$ since $f$ is continuous each $f_i$ are too

Then from $(1)$ define $i_d$:$X_i \mapsto \Pi X_i$

Then $i_d(x)$=$\pi_i(x) \circ f_i(x)$ then $r_i \circ$ $i_d$=$f_i$

I would like the solution.
I am not used to working in general Product topology.

Comment: Retract of $\prod X_i$?

Comment: I cleaned it up @Paul Frost